# How to update the helper tool in a macOS application that does privileges escalation?

Tags: objective-c, swift, macos, cocoa

I am working with privileges escalation and modern ways to achieve this in a macOS application. While testing, I have noticed that the privileged helper does not automatically get updated if you deploy a new version of the app. The existing copy in Library/PrivilegedHelperTools/ will continue to be the one to be used. In the Even better authorisation Sample Apple sample project, it confirms this :

> Caveats
>
> A real application that uses this technology will have to deal with updating its privileged helper tool.  This is harder than it
>   should be because of limitations in SMJobBless (specifically,
>   SMJobBless requests authorization /before/ doing its version check
>   ).  The best way to deal with updates is:
>
> 1. implement a 'get version' operation, that your app can use to determine the version of the installed tool
> 2. have the app update the tool if the returned version is too old
>
> The sample does not show this directly, but it does show each of the
>   steps.  For step 1, look at the code path executed by the "Get
>   Version" button.  Doing step 2 simply involves calling SMJobBless,
>   which will do the update on your behalf.

Does anybody have an example on how to actually update the helper tool with jobBless ?
Thanks for any help.